# How to remove subversion remote in git?

Tags: git, git-svn

I have a git repository that was originally created using git-svn. Now I have a git server that I push to and the svn repository has been lost. Can I remove the svn remote? How?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can edit the `.git/config` file and remove the section associated with the remote you want to remove.

The lines you want to remove probably look roughly like this:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = url-of-svn-repository/trunk
    fetch = :refs/remotes/git-svn
```

This will remove the remote from Git, but you will still have the relationship between the Git commits and the SVN commits stored in `.git/svn`.  You can remove this whole directory if you want to get rid of all your SVN remotes.  If you want to get rid of just one SVN remote and keep others, you will need to look at the directory structure and only remove the ones associated with the remote you are removing.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I also had to remove the directory at `.git/svn`.

Comment: Thanks - included in the answer now.

Comment: I hapenned to find another reference inside `.git/refs/remote/git-svn`. It is a reference to the last commit from git-svn.

Answer (score 30):

Doing it via most *nix shells, bash or mingw32:

```
cd ~/your_repo
git config --remove-section svn
```

or whatever section you have when you view the config (`cat .git/config`). For example, the next line would remove the same config section described in [Eric's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12013821/881551):

```
git config --remove-section svn-remote.svn
```

next remove all svn stuff inside the `.git` folder (svn, logs, and refs). Which is also what Sergey suggests.

```
rm -rf .git/svn .git/{logs/,}refs/remotes/{git-,}svn/
```

garbage collection just for good measure:

```
git gc
```

[source/credits](http://ao2.it/wiki/How_to_migrate_an_SVN_repository_to_Git)

Comment: My remote svn ref was stored as a file so I had to remove the trailing slash from the `rm` command, which is unneeded anyway.

Answer (score 22):

Eric's answer is correct, but not full. Even after Rafael Raposo's comment. I wish I could comment on the answer rather than posting a new one, but the rules are you can't comment until you reach 50 reputation.

The addition is:

```
find .git -type f -exec grep -nH git-svn "{}" \;
```

Showed me I had references in these two files:

```
./.git/info/refs:4:fd34a5c...8073f3 refs/remotes/git-svn
./.git/packed-refs:5:fd34a5...cd6c33 refs/remotes/git-svn
```

Until I removed those references, I could see **git-svn** doing `git log`

Comment: How did you remove those references? I don't understand.

Comment: I found that I had to go through the same process, but searching for “trunk” instead of “git-svn”, in order to get rid of the “origin/trunk” pseudo-branch.

Comment: windows version plz? ;)

Comment: I suspect you'd want to **cd** into **.git** and search for "git-svn" text in the files in there. As I mentioned, I found two of them - ".git/info/refs" and ".git/packed-refs". Open them in your favorite editor (don't use Notepad as it doesn't parse the stuff correctly and adds some garbage when you save). Open an editor and remove the lines referencing **git-svn**.

Comment: For Windows (for Linux too), you can skip the first code box, as it's just a stepping stone to find the `.git/info/refs` and `.git/packed-refs` files.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have any local config and you want to forego faffing about in the `.git` directory, simply clone the git repo from the git remote to a new directory and remove the old directory.

If you do have some simple local config (for example a different user/email to your global config), it's probably still easier to do this, and then restore any local config after cloning.

Comment: Even after doing all the above cleanups, remote tracking branches from SVN still showed up. If a clean clone is an option, it's definitely way easier than anything else.

Comment: @MartinGeisse thanks - I have no idea why anyone bothers with all the other complicated answers for this problem, when this is a simple and effective solution.