# Remove svn tags/branches from git repository, after removing svn remote

Tags: git-svn, git-tag

I've removed svn remote from my git repo, by removing it from `.git/config` and deleting `.git/svn/` according to [How to remove subversion remote in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013788/how-to-remove-subversion-remote-in-git)

Now the problem is that output of branch command is:

```
git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/tags/0.1
  remotes/tags/0.1.1
  remotes/trunk
```

How can I remove `remotes/trunk`? And `remotes/tags/0.1.1`? This is obviously from svn-related stuff, but I have no idea how to remove that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out that svn handles tags as branches, and these are all remote branches that are left. They can be removed with

```
git branch -d -r trunk
git branch -d -r tags/0.1
git branch -d -r tags/0.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in `.git/refs`, in particular `.git/refs/remotes`.

Comment: There was `origin` and `tags` directories in `.git/refs/remotes`. I've removed `tags`, nothing changed. Also what should I see there? Because I just have empty directories `.git/refs/heads` `.git/refs/remotes/origin` `.git/refs/tags`

Comment: Tags are named fixed locations (git tag).  Branches are stored in "refs".  Have you tried using the normal commands to remove a branch?  The `packed-refs` file also contains such data.